# Using Bessele in Maple returns zero

Tags: maple

I am so new in maple .
I want to execute this this function on my formula as you can see in the below image :

[image]

As you can see every operations return zero .why ?

I am so new in maple

Comment: You probably typed `zr` when you meant to type `z*r`.  Maple does not do implicit multiplication like that.

Comment: This is one of the many cases why I find the 2D notation inferior to the Maple notation - it can be obscure. Your problem here is that `zr` is interpreted as the variable $zr$ and not $z\cdot r$. This is, however, a nice and intended feature as we are then not restricted to single-letter variables and functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version? Here are the inputs/outputs for Maple V or Maple 7, they should work with yours too:

```
diff(BesselI(a, z*r),r);
> (BesselI(a+1,z*r)+a/z/r*BesselI(a,z*r))*z
```

Comment: it is 18 ,let me check it

Comment: what is 'a' here in your solution?

Comment: Sorry I read $a$ instead of $o$ in your first example. If is actually a $0$ you get `diff(BesselI(0, z*r),r) -> BesselI(1,z*r)*z`